# Having trouble running child process command

Tags: node.js, process, child-process

I am trying to execute a nodejs file called create-MySwitch.js through a child process in my main.js file.

this is the code for main.js

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var cmdStr = 'node /home/pi/Desktop/lan-device/create-MySwitch.js';
exec(cmdStr, 
    {argv: {
        port:8080,
        uuid:'MyThing'
    }},
    (error, stdout, stderr)=>{  
    if (error) {
        console.error('exec error: ${error}');
        console.log(error);
        return;
    }
    console.log('stdout: ${stdout}');
    console.log('stderr: ${stderr}');
});
```

This is how I am attempting to access the arguments in the create-MySwitch.js file

```
var port_value = process.argv.port;
var uuid_value = process.argv.uuid;
```

The output is

```
stdout: ${stdout}
stderr: ${stderr}
```

when I run the command

```
node main.js
```

I do not think it's working because the output from executing the create-MySwitch.js file should be 'ready', but clearly is not being printed in the stdout variable from the child process.
Essentially, what I am trying to do is run the command 'node createMySwitch.js  ', but instead of just typing this in to the command prompt I want to run that command using a child process. 
I am doing all of this using the raspbian operating system.

Comment: What is the reason for you to do this with `child_process` instead of simply executing the file within the same process using `require()`?

Comment: The lack of `exec error` means that the app doesn't exit with error code, that's all. You're not using template literals in console output, so ${..} variables aren't shown.